# XMLSerializer not transposing byte and int data types

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

(I [originally posted this in CodeExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134310/xml-serialize-byte-data-type), but was told it was the wrong place to put this)

I have the code to serialize my reports:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ReportSpecification{

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlElementAttribute("Reports")]
    public ReportsHolder Reports { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Version { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReportsHolder{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public List<AlertSummary> AlertSummaryReportList { get; set; }

    public ReportsHolder(){
        this.AlertSummaryReportList = new List<AlertSummary>();
    }
}
```

...and classes set up for my actual reports

```
public abstract partial class BaseReport{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string FilterMode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class AlertSummary : BaseReport{
    public AlertSummaryFilters Filters;

    private string _basicClass = "Device";

[XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string BasicClass{
    get { return _basicClass; }
    set{ if (value.Length < 0) _basicClass = value; }
}

public AlertSummary(){
    Filters = new AlertSummaryFilters();
}


[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class AlertSummaryFilters{
    public string AlertSource { get; set; }
    public byte? CriticalDevicesOnly { get; set; }
    public byte? Scope { get; set; }
    public ushort? DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public uint? DeviceGroup { get; set; }
    public uint? DeviceFacility { get; set; }
    public uint? DeviceRegion { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool CriticalDevicesOnlySpecified { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ScopeSpecified { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DeviceSpecified { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DeviceGroupSpecified { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DeviceFacilitySpecified { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DeviceRegionSpecified { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCriticalDevicesOnly() { return CriticalDevicesOnly != null; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeScope() { return Scope != null); }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceID(){ return DeviceID != null; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceGroup(){ return DeviceGroup != null; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceFacility(){ return DeviceFacility != null; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceRegion(){ return DeviceRegion != null; }

    internal AlertSummaryFilters() { }
}
```

..and I'm creating my object correctly:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Alpha.ReportSpecification));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\AlphaTest.xml");

// create the root object
Alpha.ReportSpecification myReportSpecification = new Alpha.ReportSpecification { Username = "Alpha Test", Version = (decimal)6.0 };

//create the report holder object
ReportsHolder myReportsHolder = new ReportsHolder();

// create a test AlertSummary report
AlertSummary myAlertSummary = new AlertSummary();
myAlertSummary.ReportName = "Testing AlertSummary Report from Apha";
myAlertSummary.FilterMode = "Container";
myAlertSummary.Destination = "someone@somewhere.com";
myAlertSummary.Format = "PDF";

myAlertSummary.Filters.AlertSource = "Dracula";
myAlertSummary.Filters.Scope = 22;
myAlertSummary.Filters.DeviceGroup = 12;

// add the new AlertSummary to the AlertSummary report holder
myReportsHolder.AlertSummaryReportList.Add(myAlertSummary);

// set the ReportSpecification report holder equal to the ReportsHolder
myReportSpecification.Reports = myReportsHolder;

// dump everything to the output file
serializer.Serialize(writer, myReportSpecification, ns);
writer.Close()
```

...but I am not getting the byte? datatypes in the resulting output at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReportSpecification Version="6" Username="Alpha Test">
  <Reports>
    <AlertSummaryReportList ReportName="Testing AlertSummary Report from Apha" FilterMode="Container" Destination="someone@somewhere.com" Format="PDF" BasicClass="Device">
      <Filters>
        <AlertSource>Dracula</AlertSource>

        <!-- Scope sould be here -->
        <!-- DeviceGroup should be here -->

      </Filters>
    </AlertSummaryReportList>
  </Reports>
</ReportSpecification>
```

Please help me discover what I am doing wrong, and why the Scope and DeviceGroup elements won't show up in my XML? It seems be affecting bytes and ints, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the property `Scope` is serialized is controlled by the `ScopeSpecified` property and the `ShouldSerializeScope()` method; in your class, both are present, and you don't set `ScopeSpecified` to `true`, so `Scope` isn't serialized (apparently `ScopeSpecified` takes precedence over `ShouldSerializeScope()`). Since you implemented some logic in the `ShouldSerialize*` methods, you probably don't want the `*Specified` properties. Just remove them, and it should work as expected.

Comment: A million thank-you's for this!  I was under the impression you needed both `ShouldSerialize*` and `*Specified` in order to keep things neat and tidy.

Comment: @Kulstad, no, you need only one of them. Giving the choice between the two was an unfortunate design decision in my opinion...